# How to compare rows of the same table and apply a weight from another table to each column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a sort of 'personals' matching database in MySQL.

- I need to compare a specific person in the Members table to all of the others in the same table.
- Each row (person) in the table has a number of columns with their info (age, location, religion, etc).
- I need the query to reference a table that holds my 'weights' for each column.  In other words, I want to say "location is important at 75, age-range is super important at 100, and religion is not important at 10".

Members Table

```
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| ID | Name  | Location | Religion | Age | AgeRange |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 1  | Joe   | LA       | Athiest  | 40  | 30-40    |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 2  | Mary  | LA       | Agnostic | 35  | 35-45    |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 3  | Karen | NYC      | Athiest  | 45  | 30-35    |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 4  | Lisa  | LA       | Hindu    | 30  | 45-55    |
+----+-------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

Weights Table  (how important a parameter is)

```
+----+-----+----------+----------+
| ID | Age | Location | Religion |
+----+-----+----------+----------+
| 1  | 100 | 75       | 10       |
+----+-----+----------+----------+
```

I have tried many things over the past 2 days but the latest query I was trying to play with was this, which obviously is not of huge use.  It also doesn't specify the 'person' to whom these records would be compared.

```
SELECT  a.first_name,
        g.name, 
        a.age* g.age+
        a.location* g.location+
        a.religion * g.mwReligion AS metric
    FROM members a, weight g  
    ORDER BY metric DESC;
```

My intended output would be like this:

Joe Matches:

Mary - Score = 285
(100 because she's in his AgeRange + 100 because he is in her AgeRange + 75 for Location + 10 for religion)

Lisa - Score = 175 
(100 because she is in his AgeRange + 75 for location)

Karen - Score = 10
(Only religion matches)

Comment: So the age of one person is compared to the age **range** of the other **and** the same vice versa? Can you make the age range two columns (lower and upper bounds)? Religion and location are compared by equality?

Comment: And the bounds of the age range are inclusive, i.e. 40 is in the range of 35 to 40 and so is 35?

Comment: Hey sticky bit, yes - i do have age range as separate columns (age-min and age-max).  Brain-burn!!   Yes, the bounds are inclusive.  Religion and Location are either 'true' or 'false', basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the `min_age` and `max_age` columns are separate (instead of `AgeRange`), inclusive, and of `INT` data type. The query you need should look like:

```
select 
  x.id,
  x.name,
  x.ma as match_age,
  x.ml as match_location,
  x.mr as match_religion,
  x.ma * w.age + x.ml * w.location + x.mr * w.religion as total_score
from (
  select
    o.id,
    o.name,
    case when o.age between p.min_age and p.max_age then 1 else 0 end as ma,
    case when o.location = p.location then 1 else 0 end as ml,
    case when o.religion = p.religion then 1 else 0 end as mr
  from (select * from members where id = 1) p -- selects Joe
  cross join (select * from members where id <> 1) o -- select other members
) x
cross join weights w
```

Comment: hey The Impaler - thank you SO much for taking the time. I changed "case when o.id between p.min_age and p.max_age"...    to  "o.age" instead of o.id.  Seems to be working well.  Let me test it some more and I'll report back.  I'm learning so much from your and Sticky Bit's examples.

Comment: Can't thank you enough; this works great and you not only saved me big time but I learned a ton just studying the code you posted.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like i'm missing just one thing - checking to make sure the client's age falls within the many candidates age-ranges.  I tried adding this code but still not getting a result:  

case when p.age between o.age_range_min and o.age_range_max then 1 else 0 end as ma2,

Comment: whoops, that does actually work!  (in case you want to add it to your solution).  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL Boolean expression become 0 or 1 in numeric context. So you can use your comparisons as factor.

So self join the members on the id of the one being lower than the others (otherwise, i.e. when just checking for inequality, you had each pair twice in the result). Then cross join the weights.

Now you can build your metric as sum of the multiplications of the comparisons and the weights.

I assume religion and comparison are compared by equality. The age of one person is compared to the age range of the other and the same vice versa. Further more I take the age range as splited into a lower and an upper bound and assume that the range's bounds are inclusive. Then this could look like the following:

```
SELECT m1.name,
       m2.name,
       (m1.age BETWEEN m2.agerangelower
                       AND m2.agerangeupper) * w1.age
       +
       (m2.age BETWEEN m1.agerangelower
                       AND m1.agerangeupper) * w1.age
       +
       (m1.location = m2.location) * w1.location
       +
       (m1.religion = m2.religion) * w1.religion metric
       FROM members m1
            INNER JOIN members m2
                       ON m1.id < m2.id
            CROSS JOIN weights w1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sticky Bit!  I have got The Impaler's query working, but I am also going to try yours out. At the very least to learn from it. Can't thank you enough for your time and experience.  I'll report back.

Comment: Hey Sticky Bit.  I tried that query out, but it gave me an odd result.  It showed "Joe" 3 times with different 'metric' amounts.  Then one of the girls it showed twice (with 2 different scores) and another girl only once.  I do have The Impaler's code working perfectly; but I'd still like to understand this query and if I'm doing something wrong, if you're willing to tweak it, too. Thanks again for your time.